# Combine two string variables into one in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a **JSON API** request that contains these lines (and many others)

```
"vatNumber": "${variableC},
```

I already have a variable called variableA, which generates a random number string. I also have a variable called variableB which is always going to be "01" as a string, i.e. `variableC = variableA + variableB.`

I've tried this in a preprocessor, but it doesn't work.

```
String var1 = vars.get("customerOrgNr");
String var2 = vars.get("vatSuffix"); 
vars.put("customerVatNr", var1+var2);
```

Also tried

```
"vatNumber": ${variableA}${variableB},
```

but that doesn't work either. The json request is not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "doesn't work" statement "doesn't tell" anything to us.

1. If you just need to [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) 2 values - go for  `${customerOrgNr}${vatSuffix}`, it will generate combined string
2. If you have variable like `foo01` with the value of `bar` and want to use this value - go for [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like `${__V(${customerOrgNr}${vatSuffix},)}`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

I also think you need to surround your value with quotation marks:

```
"vatNumber": "${customerVatNr}",
```

Check the request in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and check the generated JSON again i.e. [online JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: "${customerOrgNr}${vatSuffix}" straight in the JSON request works, but it doesn't work to assign that expression to a variable then use that third variable in the JSON. For my purposes I think it will do, but I'm still curious why that is.